# How to get gradient of matrix multiplication with respect to a matrix?

Tags: calculus, matrix-calculus

$$X = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_{00} & x_{01} & x_{02} \\
x_{10}& x_{11} & x_{12} \\
\end{array}
 \right]
$$

W =

w00 w01

w10 w11

w20 w21

d(XW)/d(W) = ?
How to get the gradient of matrix X multiple matrix W respect to W?

Answer (score 0):

Map $W\mapsto XW$ is linear. What do you know about derivatives of linear maps?

Comment: W and X are two matrices. Where X has shape(2, 3) W has shape(3, 2)